# Sheet7 is an Excel Object, but I have no Worksheet7

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 9 worksheets, but 10 sheet object in VBA. Somehow, Sheet7 was created in the IDE but not removed when the worksheet was deleted (I think). That is, the tabs at the bottom of my workbook show:

```
Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
Sheet4
Sheet5
Sheet6
Sheet8
Sheet9
Sheet10
```

However, the Project window of the VBA IDE shows a Microsoft Excel Object for all of those plus `Sheet7`. I cannot remove the Sheet7 object, and trying to `.Activate` it gets error 429: ActiveX can't create object. Adding a new worksheet results in Sheet11 being created. Deleting worksheets 6, 8, 9, and 10 leaves Sheet7. Creating new worksheets after that results in worksheets 6, 8, and 9 being created, skipping Sheet7. The list of Methods and Properties as suggested by Intellisense is much shorter than the methods and properties available to a "real" worksheet. For example, there is no `.Visible` property, so `Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetVisible` returns an error that Method or data member not found.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Occasionally the VB Project for a worksheet can become corrupted and you may see sheets which are not part of the workbook.  At that point it's a good idea to copy all your objects (worksheets/modules/forms etc) into a new workbook and use that going forward.  Or maybe try the Rob Bovey's code cleaner addin.    http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

Comment: Does it show up with `Dim ws as Worksheet: For each ws in ActiveWorkbook: Debug.Print ws.Name: Next ws`?

Comment: @J.Fox Nope. Looping through each Worksheet in the ThisWorkbook.sheets collection only prints out the name of the other 9 sheets. Looking at the properties dropdown of the ThisWorkbook object does not list Sheet7 as a worksheet object in ThisWorkbook. When I open the Sheet7 codepane and click the Objects dropdown, it shows "Workbook", and the 2nd drop down shows all the standard workbook events (eg, Workbook_Open, Workbook_SheetChange, etc). Its like Excel thinks Sheet7 is a workbook object.

Comment: @TimWilliams Good thought but sadly it didn't help. I exported all the modules, and it exported code from Sheet7 (which is the code I just created to see WB_Open and WB_Sheetchange). All the hidden header info (as viewed from notepad) for it is just the same as sheet1. I'll just delete Sheet7.cls and copy/move my sheets to another book as you suggest.

Comment: Not sure how it happened but I remember seeing this once.  Here is what I did: Saved modules externally, saved file as `.xlsx`, closed, opened the new file, saved-as `.xlsm`, imported modules.

Comment: u can clic sheet7 in vbe, unhide it, double clic, it should show in excel as activesheet.